# Making leader board

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with Stats of players and I got this data.

```
Stat model = id: integer, pts: float, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime
```

So there is a chance that `user_id` has 2 or more data.

```
{id: 1, pts: 2, user_id: 1, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime}

{id: 2, pts: 8, user_id: 1, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime}

{id: 3, pts: 10, user_id: 2, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime}
```

I need to get the average pts per user_id then order it by pts. To get the top scorer.

**EDIT**
I've fixed this using:

```
stat = Stat.group(:user_id).sum("pts")
new_value = Hash[*stat.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..9].flatten] # To get top 1 to 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: for the average Stat.average(:pts), for the highest scorer Stat.order(:pts).last. Hope that helps

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple query:

```
hash = Stat.group("user_id").average('pts')
```

Its will return a hash containing user_id as key and their average points scored as value.

Now to order you can order this hash as:
`Hash[h.sort_by{|k, v| v.to_i}.reverse]`

This will return a hash sorted in descending order by points.That means the first element in the hash would be the top scorer.

Note: `v.to_i` is use to handle nil cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Stat.group(:user_id).order('average_pts DESC').average(:pts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option.

In controller:

```
@users = User.joins(:stats).select("users.*, stats.user_id, stats.pts, AVG(stats.pts) avg_pts").group('stats.user_id').order("avg_pts DESC")
```

In view, to be formatted as you like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= user.name %> | <%= user.avg_pts %></p>
<% end %>
```